# I would like to set the math direct display mode in vim as seen in Sublime Text 3

Tags: filetype-tex

When I write mathematical formulas of any kind, the vim editor displays them and transforms them into a more readable format, see here: https://github.com/KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim     (the images below)

But I would like to find a setting on vim that allows me to view, not only the code, but also the result in latex language immediately below or to the right of the code formula: option given on Sublime as you can see below. [image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I don’t know if we have a formal language requirement, but as far as I know QA should be in English (for what it’s worth, it will reach a much wider audience of people who can help you!). I don’t want to discourage or prevent you from participating here. We are willing to make edits to correct understandable attempts at english; even google translate might be passable. Please [edit] with an attempt at an english translation

Comment: Thanks, D. Ben Knoble, I solved

Comment: Hm. This might be doable with popups and unicode, or something funky with neovim; the traditional way of handling this in vim is to have the pdf viewer reload after compiling side-by-side (not what i do, but something vimtex supports)

Comment: Viewing on "viewers" is not very convenient for me (and for many other students). I just wish I could see the direct preview immediately below the code or alongside, as in sublime;
If I had the expertise I would do it, but I don't know how to do it.
It would be very useful for us university students to have this mode, and since not everyone is a programmer, we are asked to create something that allows you to answer my question in a simple and complete way.
maybe create some code to insert directly in the file: .vimrc

and complete the process instantly.

Comment: not discussing it’s convenience (which I agree would be tremendous) or the ability to program; simply that it may very well be impossible in vim as you wish—vim edits text. For the most part, it doesn’t deal with anything but that—raw text. (It’s not what you would call WSYIWYG.)

Comment: The tl;dr is that Vim really sucks at displaying anything other than simple text; its graphical capabilities are extremely limited, even in the GUI versions. There are a bunch of reasons for this, and is unlikely to change in the foreseeable future. If you really want more advanced graphical capabilities then unfortunately Vim may not the best choice for you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Onivim (https://onivim.io/), it's a commercial project leveraging NeoVim that wants to build a rich UI on top of Vim and might end up supporting native visualization such as the one you want. It's an early project and it's also a commercial project (you need a license to use it) but you might want to ask them if they're planning to build something like what you describe here... I hope this helps!